# Issue In connecting Angular 10 with Spring security to retrieve data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, httpclient, angular10

I have been facing some issues in connecting spring-boot/spring-security with angular 10 in retrieving data and response from the backend.

After logging in, Error is occurs on my default page of my application.
I am Stuck on the same error for the past few days. Please Help!

Error is thrown on the backend side:
**Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception**

**org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:369) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]**

**Web Configure File:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home/**","/user/login",  
                "/admin/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .disable().formLogin().permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
        http.cors();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Configuration
    public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins(
                            "http://localhost:4200")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD").allowedHeaders("*")
            ;
        }

    }
```

**User Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin(/* origins = "http://localhost:4200" */origins="*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestBody loginDetails data) {
        try {
            String username = data.getUsername();
            System.out.println("Checking...");
            System.out.println(data.getUsername());
            System.out.println(data.getPassword());
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, data.getPassword()));
            // String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username,
            // this.users.findByEmail(username).getRoles());
            System.out.println("abcdefg");
            Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("username", username);
            // model.put("token", token);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            
              //throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid email/password supplied");
            return new ResponseEntity<>("invalid", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            //return false;
        }
        //return new ResponseEntity<>("valid", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class ElectronicsController {
@GetMapping("/default")
    public List<ElectronicSellDAO> homePageDefault() {
        System.out.println("Home Default........");
        return electronicsService.getDefaultData();
    }
}
```

**Angular Service:**

```
  this.test=userService.getProducts();
    this.test.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
  }, 
  error=>{
      console.log(error);
  })
//get function
  getProducts(){

    console.log("Get Request");
    
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/home/default`);
 
  }
```

**Error on Console:**
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/login"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/login"

Comment: What URL you are using from angular to hit login page?

Comment: yes, Actually the problem was related to the URL which I have used as environment.apiURL. Thank you